# How to get all DynamoDB attributes without typing all of them

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm currently trying to return all the attributes of an entry based off the primary key in Lambda, but I don't want to type out every single attribute to get. Is there an optimized way to do this instead of typing out every single one?

Here is my lambda function:

```
exports.handler = async function(event, ctx, callback) {
  var data;
  var params = {
    Key: {
      key: event.key
    },
    TableName : 'app',
    AttributesToGet: [
      'email', 
      'lastName',
      'firstName',
      '...nextAttribute',
      '...nextAttribute'
    ],
  };

  try {
    data = await dynamoDb.get(params).promise()
    console.log(data);
  } 
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  return data.Item;
}
```

So in this example, instead of return `...nextAttribute` is there a way to return all the attributes?

Answer (score 5):

You do not have to specify `AttributsToGet`. If you omit it, you will get all attributes by default, e.g.

```
exports.handler = async function(event, ctx, callback) {
  const params = {
    Key: {
      key: event.key
    },
    TableName : 'app',
  };

  try {
    const data = await dynamoDb.get(params).promise();
    console.log(data);
    return data.Item;
  } 
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return undefined;
  }
}
```

See details in the AWS JavaScript API, specifically the [getItem()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#getItem-property) function of DynamoDB.

---

Alternatively, you may find the DynamoDB [DocumentClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#get-property) interesting. Copied from the [get()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#get-property) documentation:

```
var params = {
  TableName : 'Table',
  Key: {
    HashKey: 'hashkey'
  }
};

var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

documentClient.get(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  else console.log(data);
});
```

---

Side note, `AttributesToGet` is a legacy parameter according to the documentation. Consider using `ProjectionExpression` instead if you change your mind and would like to be explicit about which attributes to fetch.